# How can I add styling to an event listener in an class component in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to make an animated burger menu with an event listener that mounts on load. The event listener works but the transition between the two stylings I toggle between does not work. Code below. I'm sure that my method of toggling between preset styles is wrong, whether or not it's part of the problem. Thanks.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import '../style/Main.css'
import styled from "styled-components"

const originalBurger = styled.div`
    display: inline;
    div {
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
        height: 4px;
        width: 42px;
        margin: 10px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease forwards;
    }
`;

const animatedBurger = styled.div`
    display: inline;
    div {
        background-color: #000000;
        height: 4px;
        width: 42px;
        margin: 10px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease forwards;
        &:nth-child(1) {
            transform: rotate(45deg)
        }
        &:nth-child(2) {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        &:nth-child(3) {
            transform: rotate(315deg);
        }
    }
`;

let StyledBurger = originalBurger;

class Burger extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (StyledBurger === animatedBurger) {
                StyledBurger = originalBurger;
                this.forceUpdate();
            } else if (StyledBurger === originalBurger) {
                StyledBurger = animatedBurger;
                this.forceUpdate();
            }
            this.componentDidMount();
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).removeEventListener();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <StyledBurger>
                <div />
                <div />
                <div />
            </StyledBurger>
        )
    }
}

export default Burger
```

**UPDATE**

used the help of the approved answer and ended with this

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import '../style/Main.css'
import styled from "styled-components"

const getActiveStyle = (props) =>  `
    &:nth-child(1) {
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 12px)
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10px, -12px);
    }
`
const originalBurger = styled.div`
    display: inline;
    div {
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
        height: 6px;
        width: 50px;
        margin: 10px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        ${(props) => props.isActive ? getActiveStyle(props) : ""}
    }
`;

let StyledBurger = originalBurger;

class Burger extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            isActive: false
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <StyledBurger isActive={this.state.isActive} onClick={()=> this.setState({isActive: !this.state.isActive})}>
                <div />
                <div />
                <div />
            </StyledBurger>
        )
    }
}
export default Burger;
```

Comment: you might separate the style of the ham burger menu  into a CSS file and create a state to change the style on click event instead of `forceUpdate()`

Comment: Why addEventListener? Why not put an onClick prop on the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are much better and simpler way to achieve it.
In your style component you can have a props for active/inactive state. It is documented here: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props
The code can look likes this:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import '../style/Main.css'
import styled from "styled-components"

const getActiveStyle = (props) =>  `
    &:nth-child(1) {
        transform: rotate(45deg)
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
        transform: rotate(315deg);
    }
`
const originalBurger = styled.div`
    display: inline;
    div {
        background-color: props.isActive ? #000000 : #fcfcfc;
        height: 4px;
        width: 42px;
        margin: 10px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease forwards;
        ${(props) => props.isActive ? getActiveStyle(props) : ""}
    }
`;

let StyledBurger = originalBurger;

class Burger extends Component {
    constructor(){
        this.state = {
            isActive: false
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <StyledBurger isActive={this.state.isActive} onClick={()=> this.setState({isActive: !this.state.isActive})}>
                <div />
                <div />
                <div />
            </StyledBurger>
        )
    }
}
export default Burger;
```